# Smooth scroll to anchor on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need smooth scroll to anchor on js, i've found an example and when I use it I have error in console, can anybody help me to solve this problem?

```
scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
if (duration <= 0) return;
var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
var perTick = difference / duration * 10;
var elmnt = document.getElementById("how-it-work");

setTimeout(function() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
    scrollTo(document.body, elmnt.offsetTop, 600);
}, 10);
}
```

And in console I have errors:
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined(…)
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined

Comment: What element are you applying to scrollTo()?

Comment: @Roberrrt scrollTo(document.body, elmnt.offsetTop, 600);

Comment: This should be called upon DOM ready. When using jQuery, that's inside $(function() { ... } );. My guess is you're calling this before the page actually loaded fully so there is no #how-it-work yet.